# making nodemailer send emails with different gmail accounts

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail-api, nodemailer

i authenticate with passportjs with success but nodemailer only send emails with one email which is the one used in the console.cloud.google.

wheni try other gmail accounts, i get this error:

> Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
> Learn more at 535 5.7.8
> https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u6sm13346885wrp.0 -
> gsmtp
> at SMTPConnection._formatError (/var/www/html/Recrute/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:784:19)
> at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/var/www/html/Recrute/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1536:34)
> at SMTPConnection. (/var/www/html/Recrute/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1515:26)
> at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/var/www/html/Recrute/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:947:20)
> at SMTPConnection._onData (/var/www/html/Recrute/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:749:14)
> at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (/var/www/html/Recrute/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:189:44)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
> at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
> at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
> at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10) {   code: 'EAUTH',   response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not
> accepted. Learn more at\n' +
> '535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials u6sm13346885wrp.0 - gsmtp',   responseCode: 535,   command: 'AUTH
> XOAUTH2' }

i added all the emails to test users.

the code

````
      type: 'oauth2',
      user: req.user.email,
      clientId: clientId,
      clientSecret: clientSecret,
      refreshToken: refreshToken,
  };
  
  var mailOptions = {
      from: req.user.email,
      to: 'email@gmail.com',
      subject: req.query.sbjct,
      text: req.query.msg,
      html: req.query.msg,
  };
  
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      auth: auth,
  });
  
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
      } else {
          res.send('done !');
      } ```
````

Comment: You should enable "less secure" on your Gmail Id(https://hotter.io/docs/email-accounts/secure-app-gmail/) and try again

Comment: the thing is i am avoiding that, i don't want to force users to do that

Answer (score 0):

Gmail does not fully allow sending mails from third party apps. So for you to send mails from a third party app (like your app using nodemailer) you need to go to that gmail account settings and lower gmail security for that account [less secure][1]. [nodemailer docs](https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/)

and your createTransport should look like this

```
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.gmail.email",
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: your username, // generated gmail user
      pass: your password, // generated gmail password
    },
  });
```